# Google Apps Script Web app to create folder in user's myDrive folder only sends files to MY my Drive (the creator of the app)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, directory

I am writing a web app that will allow students to click a button to create a set of folders & files in their own drive taken from a spreadsheet. My problem is that for some reason when anyone else clicks on the button in the web app, the folder is always made in my own drive, and never the students!

**edit: it recognizes the correct user as the active user but still creates the file in my drive not theirs**

I've made apps like this before that copied files (not folders) into the user's Drive, and those work fine, but for some reason this doesn't. Is it because I'm creating a brand new folder instead of copying it? The web apps i'd created before always asked the user for permission to look at their drive & edit folders etc but this one doesn't. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

I even tried setting the ownership to the user but it still gets created in my own drive it's driving me nuts. Is there a way to move a folder into a user's my drive through apps script? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

```
var sheet = '1kM7GeBubLRDC_L_G0rrlddHARSL59DkmWco6Z72gJAg';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet).getActiveSheet();   //SPREADSHEET


var netID = Session.getActiveUser();        
var title = ss.getRange("D1").getValue();


var mainFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(title);
var mainFolderID = mainFolder.getId();
var portfolio = DriveApp.getFolderById(mainFolderID);
portfolio.setOwner(netID + "@nyu.edu");
Logger.log(getOwner(portfolio));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with how the script is published, you have it set up to execute as you, so the items are created on your drive.

Under the **"Deploy as a web app..."** settings check the option **"Execute the app as"** , the value needs to be "User accessing the web app" instead of "Me".

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHH jesus christ hahaha

Comment: no problem :)  it's an easy thing to miss since it works fine when you're testing with your own account